# Maximum limit of records in coreplot

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is there a maximum limit of records that can be plotted by CorePlot? In my project, when the no of records returned cross a limit of 2000, app crashes due to memory warnings. But I need to plot a no around 24 x 300. Can any one help me?

Comment: Is the only memory you are using going into plotting this graph? Is there memory elsewhere that you can release? Perhaps in image caches?

Comment: Instrument do not show any leaks. But memory allocation increases on showing large no of data.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I'm asking is there any other memory in your app that you could free up to use for your CorePlot? If you have any caches you could perhaps purge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Plot caches its data internally in a compact format (basically a c-style array). You can reduce the space required by setting the `cachePrecision` on each plot to `CPTPlotCachePrecisionDouble`. This forces it to use doubles for the cache (8 bytes for each data point) instead of possibly using NSDecimal (20 bytes each).

When does your app crash? When loading the data into Core Plot? When drawing?

Comment: Crash is happening when it drawing graph.

Comment: What type of plot is it? I've tested scatter plots with 10,000+ points and while its a little slow, it doesn't crash. Can you post your setup code so we can see how the graph and plots are configured?

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of points to plot. Have you considered only plotting what the user can see? The coding can be troublesome but it is possible.

You might also consider not using CorePlot, but rather a custom graph with thin data structures that don't use much memory. I coded a pretty handy stock chart in about a week based on this tutorial:

http://buildmobile.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d/#fbid=EKAB22zV7It

I can share my UIView subclass if you want to see how I handle it. However, I can't vouch for 7200 data points because I plot at max 250.

Good luck,

Damien